# Replace MySQL column data with new data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

Hello so I currently have an old members table to a forum that I'm trying to import into my new database for a new forum. However, I want to reset all of their group_id column back to 1 which is a basic member.

So right now all of their groups_id's are scattered depending on what group they were in. I just want to go into the table 'forum_members' and change EVERYONE'S column named 'group_id' to a value of '1'

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
UPDATE forum_members SET group_id = 1;
```

For more info about the `UPDATE` syntax, check MySQL Reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Ah... I was taking the wrong approach. Thank you. I'll accept your answer once the timeout is over. Thanks a lot!